# Самый простой и лаконичный способ убрать лишние скобки

Tags: c, строки, c++

Имеется string с арифметическим выражением, есть какой-нибудь быстрый и простой способ убрать лишние скобки (только по краям, скобки внутри выражение убирать не нужно)

"(3+5)" - убрать

"(3+5)*(4-2)" - оставить

"(3*(4-2))" - убрать

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовав совет пользователя [Fike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/16095/fike), написал следующую процедуру:

```
void stripBrackets(string &str)
{
    if (str[0] == '(')
    {
        int level = 1;
        for (unsigned int i = 1; i < str.length(); ++i)
        {
            if (str[i] == '(') { ++level; }
            else if (str[i] == ')') { --level; }
            if (level == 0)
            {
                if (i == str.length() - 1)
                {
                    str = str.substr(1, str.length() - 2);
                }
                else
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Простите, но элегантным это назвать у меня язык не повернется))

Comment: Я на самом деле не сишник, и мне (возможно, неверно) кажется, что у вас счет дополнительных скобок идет с третьего, а не со второго символа (из-за ++i, а не i++)

Comment: @Fike, если такое выражение изолировано от остальных и ее промежуточный результат нигде не сохраняется, то не важно. Убер-программисты ставят ++i вместо i++ в таких случаях потому, что таким образом не будет создаваться временная переменная (компиляторы скорее всего об этом знают и оптимизируют, но мастерство не пропьешь =)) ).

Comment: @artyomdevyatov, нормальный код. 

Может только так:


    if (str[0] == '(') {
        int level = 1;

        for (int i = 1; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (str[i] == '(') 
              ++level; 
            else if ((str[i] == ')') && (--level == 0)) {
              if (i == str.length() - 1)
                str = str.substr(1, str.length() - 2);
              break;
            }
        }
    }


чуть красивей (на мой вкус).

Answer (score 0):

Если строки всегда валидные (скобки стоят правильно и парно), то считаешь `std::count` количество '(', затем через `std::find` находишь итераторы для крайних '(' и ')' и удаляешь.

Comment: "(3+5)*(4-2)" - 4 скобки, удалю левую и правую скобку и получу "3+5)*(4-2"

Или я что-то не так понял?

Comment: Как определить, что во втором примере их можно оставить, а в третьем убрать? И там и там 4 скобки

Comment: @artyomdevyatov, можно пройти весь текст со счетчиком незакрытых скобок. Как только он упал до нуля, проверяется позиция курсора, и, если он в этот момент находится не в самом конце текста, удалять ничего нельзя.

Comment: Точно, спасибо! Надеюсь, этот метод поможет во всех возможных вариантах

Comment: Да, точно) Нюансов достаточно. Элегантнее самописного стека итераторов с ходу придумать в пятницу вечером не выходит =)

Comment: @Fike
Вариант хороший! А если так: (3х(4-2))х3

Comment: @Free_ze: это не пройдёт в условие: 

> только по краям

Comment: @Free_ze, тогда анализировать наличие скобок в оставшемся тексте. (update: а вот и нет, там все-таки придется разбирать выражение, чтобы корректно обработалось (3+2)*7)  
Вы сейчас просто будете постепенно усложнять задачу и придете в результате к shunting yard algorithm, который, конечно, клеви, но здесь вряд ли нужен и будет сложен в поддержке.

Comment: @VladD
Имелись в виду крайние (избыточные) скобки, а не вообще крайние. Говорю же, нюансов больше, чем кажется.

Comment: @Free_ze очень хотелось бы услышать комментарии по поводу моего кода. Мне его показывать придется, не хотелось бы опозориться)

Comment: А почему бы не проверять арифметические операции?

Если слева или справа от выражения стоит умножение или деление, то убирать скобки не надо. Если же стоят плюс или минус, то можно убирать. Соответственно для больших операций можно ввести приоритеты и смотреть по ним.

Как итог, ищем скобку '(' и смотрим, что стоит слева от нее. Потом ищем ее пару ')' и смотрим на знак справа. В зависимости от знаков удаляем или нет. Дополнительные проверки на валидность по желанию можно добавить.

Comment: @Alexey123
Вооооот =) Короче, @artyomdevyatov, если хочешь быть честен перед совестью, начинай проектировать маленький парсер, десятистрочником ты все возможные операции не обыграешь, а если и обыграешь, то это будет вырвиглазный код с глубокой вложенностью. Нужны какие-то сущности и состояния.

Comment: @Free_ze о господи, да вы хоть целью сначала понитересуйтесь. Ему, может, надо слегка какой-то вывод причесать, не более. Тут же не вопрос "здравствуйте, я пишу энтерпрайз и мне на голову насели бухгалтеры аки коршуны".